# How to get the path to the .csx script being executed?

Tags: c#, csx, csi

When executing a C# script (`.csx`) with `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\amd64\csi.exe`, how do I get the path to the script being executed?

The line

```
Console.WriteLine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
```

prints the path to the interpreter (`csi.exe`), not the script.

The script should be aware of it's path at some level, as you can load assemblies with a relative path like this:

```
#r "..\\bla\\asdf.dll"
```

Comment: You must specify the full path of the location of the script file.  VS will default to the bin folder of the project if full path is not specified.

Answer (score 2):

Only by using a helper method, could I programatically obtain the full path to the .CSX source script. The method uses the [CallerFilePath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerfilepathattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) attribute. This works from inside the interactive Rosalyn C# shell, as well as command line.

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
// Work-around helper method to get the source file location.
private static string GetSourceFile([CallerFilePath] string file = "") => file;
Console.WriteLine($"Full path to .csx source file => {GetSourceFile()}");
```